# Null pointer exception on button click in a listview

Tags: listview, android-intent, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I have listview which when long pressed on a listitem adds the listitem to the favourites using the shared preferences. When the item is clicked it opens up a new activity. The activity contains a favourite button which should do the same function as the item is long clicked i.e adding the listitem which open the activity to favourites. For this I pass in position of the listitem through intent in item click listener method. This is what I tried.

**onitemclicklistener of my main activity**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), SingleItemView.class);
        intent.putExtra("item position", position);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**singleitemview.java**

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity
{
ProductListAdapter padaptr;
SharedPreference sharedPreference;

List<Product> products;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.singleitem);
    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();



    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singleitemButton1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            int posc= extras.getInt("item position");
            Product product = (Product) padaptr.getItem(posc);
            ImageView button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);

            if (checkFavoriteItem(product)) {

                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
                button.setTag("red");
            } else {
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
                button.setTag("grey");
            }
        }

            private boolean checkFavoriteItem(Product checkProduct) {
                boolean check = false;
                List<Product> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(getApplicationContext());
                if (favorites != null) {
                    for (Product product : favorites) {
                        if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                            check = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return check;
            }
    });
    }


  }
```

Now when I press the button the app crashes giving null pointer exception in logcat at the line

```
Product product = (Product) padaptr.getItem(posc);
```

**logcat**

```
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.mycompany.myapp.SingleItemView$100000000.onClick(SingleItemView.java:39)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:148)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18428)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-26 19:43:23.687 21810 21810 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ProductListAdapter padaptr; is never initialized? And, couldn't you just pass in the item through an intent?

Answer (score 1):

The logcat have the reason. The "padaptr" Is null.

Maybe the solution could be pass the complete object throught activities.

Here a tutorial:

http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/passing-objects-between-activities.html

But, I use my own method. I use the Jackson Library.

I convert the object to Json String, and I pass the object as string in extras and in the new activity I convert the Json to object.

Here a tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Good Luck!

Comment: Thx bro i will have ablook at it and try it